Glue DynamicFrame join results in empty schema and no data
Glue 5.0
Having issues where the DynamicFrame join is resulting in no data.
As shown in the code below:

It's performing a flatten of the data.
Then it attempts to join the root_component.supporting_info to root.

Below is the sample code and output.  I'm fixing to experiment with the raw spark frame to see if its reproducible there.
unnested = dyf.relationalize("root", "s3://mybucket/temp/")
print("#####KEYS####")
print(unnested.keys())
print("#####KEYS####")
print("")
dyf_root = unnested.select("root")
print("#####ROOT DATA####")
dyf_root.toDF().show(vertical=True)
print("#####ROOT DATA####")
print("")
dyf_root_supporting_info = unnested.select("root_component.supporting_info")
print("#####ROOT SUPPORTING INFO####")
dyf_root_supporting_info.toDF().show(vertical=True)
print("#####ROOT SUPPORTING INFO####")
print("")
dyf_joined = dyf_root.join(paths1=["component.supporting_info"], paths2=["id"], frame2=dyf_root_supporting_info)
print("#####JOINED SCHEMA#####")
dyf_joined.printSchema()
print("#####JOINED SCHEMA#####")
print("")
print("#####JOINED DATA#####")
dyf_joined.toDF().show(vertical=True)
print("#####JOINED DATA#####")

Output:
#####KEYS####
dict_keys(['root', 'root_component.tuple.licenses', 'root_component.supporting_info', 'root_image_tags', 'root_component.raw_tuple.licenses', 'root_component.original_tuple.licenses', 'root_component.supporting_info.val.cpes'])
#####KEYS####

#####ROOT DATA####
-RECORD 0-------------------------------------------------------------
 image_id                                      | 1127318              
 product_id                                    | 600                  
 scan_id                                       | 1727750              
 action_id                                     | 665a693e3d03044f1... 
 action_timestamp                              | 2024-06-01T00:20:... 
 image_tags                                    | 1                    
 component.found_by                            | protecode            
 component.image_id                            | 1127318              
 component.raw_tuple.component_type            | Open Source          
 component.raw_tuple.latest_known_version      | 2.7.3                
 component.raw_tuple.maven_id                  | xalan:xalan          
 component.raw_tuple.licenses                  | 1                    
 component.raw_tuple.name                      | xalan                
 component.raw_tuple.version                   | 2.7.2                
 component.raw_tuple.supplier                  | apache               
 component.raw_tuple.codetype                  | java                 
 component.raw_tuple.tuple_id                  | b9fff82793e1ddb9f... 
 component.raw_tuple.homepage                  | null                 
 component.reusable_module_id                  | 1127318              
 component.tuple.component_type                | Open Source          
 component.tuple.latest_known_version          | 2.7.3                
 component.tuple.maven_id                      | xalan:xalan          
 component.tuple.licenses                      | 1                    
 component.tuple.name                          | xalan                
 component.tuple.version                       | 2.7.2                
 component.tuple.supplier                      | apache               
 component.tuple.codetype                      | java                 
 component.tuple.tuple_id                      | b9fff82793e1ddb9f... 
 component.tuple.homepage                      | null                 
 component.origin_id                           | 665a693e3d03044f1... 
 component.original_tuple.component_type       | Open Source          
 component.original_tuple.latest_known_version | 2.7.3                
 component.original_tuple.maven_id             | xalan:xalan          
 component.original_tuple.licenses             | 1                    
 component.original_tuple.name                 | xalan                
 component.original_tuple.version              | 2.7.2                
 component.original_tuple.supplier             | apache               
 component.original_tuple.codetype             | java                 
 component.original_tuple.tuple_id             | b9fff82793e1ddb9f... 
 component.original_tuple.homepage             | null                 
 component.supporting_info                     | 1                    
 component.id                                  | 665a693e3d03044f1... 
 gc_image                                      | true                 
-RECORD 1-------------------------------------------------------------
 image_id                                      | 1127318              
 product_id                                    | 600                  
 scan_id                                       | 1727750              
 action_id                                     | 665a693e3d03044f1... 
 action_timestamp                              | 2024-06-01T00:20:... 
 image_tags                                    | 2                    
 component.found_by                            | protecode            
 component.image_id                            | 1127318              
 component.raw_tuple.component_type            | null                 
 component.raw_tuple.latest_known_version      | 6.9.0                
 component.raw_tuple.maven_id                  | org.apache.bcel:bcel 
 component.raw_tuple.licenses                  | 2                    
 component.raw_tuple.name                      | bcel                 
 component.raw_tuple.version                   | 2.7.2                
 component.raw_tuple.supplier                  | apache               
 component.raw_tuple.codetype                  | java                 
 component.raw_tuple.tuple_id                  | c4c44c1c3ad99644d... 
 component.raw_tuple.homepage                  | https://commons.a... 
 component.reusable_module_id                  | 1127318              
 component.tuple.component_type                | Open Source          
 component.tuple.latest_known_version          | 6.9.0                
 component.tuple.maven_id                      | org.apache.bcel:bcel 
 component.tuple.licenses                      | 2                    
 component.tuple.name                          | bcel                 
 component.tuple.version                       | 2.7.2                
 component.tuple.supplier                      | apache               
 component.tuple.codetype                      | java                 
 component.tuple.tuple_id                      | c4c44c1c3ad99644d... 
 component.tuple.homepage                      | https://commons.a... 
 component.origin_id                           | 665a693e3d03044f1... 
 component.original_tuple.component_type       | Open Source          
 component.original_tuple.latest_known_version | 6.9.0                
 component.original_tuple.maven_id             | org.apache.bcel:bcel 
 component.original_tuple.licenses             | 2                    
 component.original_tuple.name                 | bcel                 
 component.original_tuple.version              | 2.7.2                
 component.original_tuple.supplier             | apache               
 component.original_tuple.codetype             | java                 
 component.original_tuple.tuple_id             | c4c44c1c3ad99644d... 
 component.original_tuple.homepage             | https://commons.a... 
 component.supporting_info                     | 2                    
 component.id                                  | 665a693e3d03044f1... 
 gc_image                                      | true                 

#####ROOT DATA####

#####ROOT SUPPORTING INFO####
-RECORD 0-------------------------------------------------------------
 id                                            | 1                    
 index                                         | 0                    
 component.supporting_info.val.sha1            | 9ee6066b9f7152234... 
 component.supporting_info.val.path            | alu-sr-cli-8.49/p... 
 component.supporting_info.val.package_name    | xalan:xalan          
 component.supporting_info.val.confidence      | 0.67                 
 component.supporting_info.val.matching_method | signature            
 component.supporting_info.val.cpes            | 1                    
-RECORD 1-------------------------------------------------------------
 id                                            | 2                    
 index                                         | 0                    
 component.supporting_info.val.sha1            | 9ee6066b9f7152234... 
 component.supporting_info.val.path            | alu-sr-cli-8.49/p... 
 component.supporting_info.val.package_name    | org.apache.bcel:bcel 
 component.supporting_info.val.confidence      | 0.77                 
 component.supporting_info.val.matching_method | signature            
 component.supporting_info.val.cpes            | 2                    

#####ROOT SUPPORTING INFO####

#####JOINED SCHEMA#####
root

#####JOINED SCHEMA#####

#####JOINED DATA#####
(0 rows)

#####JOINED DATA#####



So the issue most likely is around the "." in the keys being periods are fairly interesting to deal with in spark colymns.  I've tried to evaluate an option to pass as part of relationalize that would set the default seperator, but haven't found one.

Confirmed, if I change dyf_joined = dyf_root.join(paths1=["component.supporting_info"], paths2=["id"], frame2=dyf_root_supporting_info) to dyf_joined = dyf_root.join(paths1=["`component.supporting_info`"], paths2=["id"], frame2=dyf_root_supporting_info) it seems to work.  Would love to see if there is an option to relationalize that would avoid the period all together, docs seem lacking to the options.

# Relationalize the data
unnested = dyf.relationalize("root", "s3://mybucket/temp/")

# Print the keys
print("#####KEYS####")
print(unnested.keys())
print("#####KEYS####")
print("")

# Select the root data
dyf_root = unnested.select("root")

# Print the root data
print("#####ROOT DATA####")
dyf_root.toDF().show(truncate=False, vertical=True)
print("#####ROOT DATA####")
print("")

# Select the supporting info data
dyf_root_supporting_info = unnested.select("root_component.supporting_info")

# Print the supporting info data
print("#####ROOT SUPPORTING INFO####")
dyf_root_supporting_info.toDF().show(truncate=False, vertical=True)
print("#####ROOT SUPPORTING INFO####")
print("")

# Join the root data with the supporting info data
dyf_joined = dyf_root.join(
    paths1=["component.supporting_info"],
    paths2=["id"],
    frame2=dyf_root_supporting_info
)

# Print the joined schema
print("#####JOINED SCHEMA#####")
dyf_joined.printSchema()
print("#####JOINED SCHEMA#####")
print("")

# Print the joined data
print("#####JOINED DATA#####")
dyf_joined.toDF().show(truncate=False, vertical=True)
print("#####JOINED DATA#####")


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
